# Fourier series and Toeplitz matrix

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, convex-optimization, control-theory, signal-processing

Assume the truncated discrete Fourier series of a function $f(x)$:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=-N}^N C_n e^{2\pi n x i /L}
$$
where $L$ is the period of $f(x)$. There is a rule for $f(x)$ which claims,
$$
\forall x \in [0, L]  :\ \ f(x)>0 \iff T_f \succeq 0
$$
where $T_f$ is the Toeplitz matrix.
Here my question is how can we extend this result for multidimensional Fourier series: For example: consider the function $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) : [0,L_1] \times [0,L_2] \times ... [0,L_n]\to \mathbb{R}$ which can be formulated as:
$$
f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)= \sum_{m_1=-N}^N\sum_{m_2=-N}^N... \sum_{m_n=-N}^N C_{m_1m_2...m_n} e^{2\pi i(\frac{m_1 x_1}{L_1}+\frac{m_2 x_2}{L_2}+...+\frac{m_n x_n}{L_n})}
$$
How can we extend the mentioned result for one dimensional Discrete fourier series to this multidimensional one? I guess we should talk about tensors in this case. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you should talk about tensors in this case but what you are thinking of doing seems to be very difficult. First of all, you will have to adapt the formalism of the Toeplitz matrix associated with your decomposition to the multidimensional case. The order of the tensor will be $n$ but it is unclear what is dimension will be. It should also be built in such a way that it is symmetric. This is not trivial. Then, you will be able to check the eigenvalues of your tensor.

Comment: Thanks , can you introduce me a paper or book regarding this subject, I really need to read it , I haven’t seen anywhere a text about this extension.

Comment: Which subject exactly. If it is about what I described above, there is none to the best of my knowledge. You can start by looking at positive semidefiniteness of tensors, understand where does the result in the one-dimensional case come from, and try to generalize it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I have searched a lot, and I didn't find anything